# Apache Derby simple update statement performance becomes 1500% worse when adding one byte to a column

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, derby

I have 2 tables as follows:

```
ParentUpdate
name varchar(255)
value int not null
```

primary key: name

```
ChildUpdate
parentName varchar(255)
name varchar(255)
value int
data varchar(1000)
```

primary key: name
foreign key: parentName to ParentUpdate.name

When I run the statement "update ChildUpdate set parentName = 'Parent 2' where parentName = 'Parent 1'" with 2500 records in the ChildUpdate table and 1 record in the ParentUpdate table with only a single byte difference in data size in the ChildUpdate table, the performance decreases by 15 times.

When the ChildUpdate data column has exactly 14 bytes of the same character the runtime of the above query is about 500 milliseconds.  When I add one more byte to the data column of ChildUpdate the performance all of a sudden becomes about 7500 milliseconds.

If i then decrease the data size back to 14 from 15 it's fast again.  When i put it back to 15 it's slow again.  This is reproducible every time.

Can you please help me figure out how to get the same fast performance without such seemingly random behaviour.

The query plans are below for both cases.

```
    Statement Name: 
    null
Statement Text: 
    update ChildUpdate set parentName = 'Parent 2' where parentName = 'Parent 1'
Parse Time: 16
Bind Time: 0
Optimize Time: 0
Generate Time: 0
Compile Time: 16
Execute Time: -1453199411351
Begin Compilation Timestamp : 2016-01-19 05:30:11.32
End Compilation Timestamp : 2016-01-19 05:30:11.336
Begin Execution Timestamp : 2016-01-19 05:30:11.351
End Execution Timestamp : 2016-01-19 05:30:11.773
Statement Execution Plan Text: 
Update ResultSet using row locking:
deferred: false
Rows updated = 2500
Indexes updated = 2
Execute Time = -1453199411383
    Normalize ResultSet:
    Number of opens = 1
    Rows seen = 2500
        constructor time (milliseconds) = 0
        open time (milliseconds) = 0
        next time (milliseconds) = 16
        close time (milliseconds) = 16
        optimizer estimated row count: 51.50
        optimizer estimated cost: 796.12
    Source result set:
        Project-Restrict ResultSet (2):
        Number of opens = 1
        Rows seen = 2500
        Rows filtered = 0
        restriction = false
        projection = true
            constructor time (milliseconds) = 0
            open time (milliseconds) = 0
            next time (milliseconds) = 16
            close time (milliseconds) = 16
            restriction time (milliseconds) = 0
            projection time (milliseconds) = 0
            optimizer estimated row count: 51.50
            optimizer estimated cost: 796.12
        Source result set:
            Table Scan ResultSet for CHILDUPDATE at read committed isolation level using exclusive row locking chosen by the optimizer
            Number of opens = 1
            Rows seen = 2500
            Rows filtered = 0
            Fetch Size = 1
                constructor time (milliseconds) = 0
                open time (milliseconds) = 15
                next time (milliseconds) = 16
                close time (milliseconds) = 16
                next time in milliseconds/row = 0

            scan information:
                Bit set of columns fetched={0, 1}
                Number of columns fetched=2
                Number of pages visited=41
                Number of rows qualified=2500
                Number of rows visited=2500
                Scan type=heap
                start position:
                    null
                stop position:
                    null
                qualifiers:
                    Column[0][0] Id: 0
                    Operator: =
                    Ordered nulls: false
                    Unknown return value: false
                    Negate comparison result: false
                optimizer estimated row count: 51.50
                optimizer estimated cost: 796.12
total time: ~500 milliseconds
```

and the slow version

```
    Statement Name: 
    null
Statement Text: 
    update ChildUpdate set parentName = 'Parent 2' where parentName = 'Parent 1'
Parse Time: 0
Bind Time: 0
Optimize Time: 0
Generate Time: 0
Compile Time: 0
Execute Time: -1453199485700
Begin Compilation Timestamp : 2016-01-19 05:31:25.684
End Compilation Timestamp : 2016-01-19 05:31:25.684
Begin Execution Timestamp : 2016-01-19 05:31:25.7
End Execution Timestamp : 2016-01-19 05:31:33.141
Statement Execution Plan Text: 
Update ResultSet using row locking:
deferred: true
Rows updated = 2500
Indexes updated = 2
Execute Time = -1453199485747
    Normalize ResultSet:
    Number of opens = 1
    Rows seen = 2500
        constructor time (milliseconds) = 0
        open time (milliseconds) = 0
        next time (milliseconds) = 47
        close time (milliseconds) = 0
        optimizer estimated row count: 51.50
        optimizer estimated cost: 810.94
    Source result set:
        Project-Restrict ResultSet (3):
        Number of opens = 1
        Rows seen = 2500
        Rows filtered = 0
        restriction = false
        projection = true
            constructor time (milliseconds) = 0
            open time (milliseconds) = 0
            next time (milliseconds) = 32
            close time (milliseconds) = 0
            restriction time (milliseconds) = 0
            projection time (milliseconds) = 0
            optimizer estimated row count: 51.50
            optimizer estimated cost: 810.94
        Source result set:
            Project-Restrict ResultSet (2):
            Number of opens = 1
            Rows seen = 2500
            Rows filtered = 0
            restriction = false
            projection = true
                constructor time (milliseconds) = 0
                open time (milliseconds) = 0
                next time (milliseconds) = 32
                close time (milliseconds) = 0
                restriction time (milliseconds) = 0
                projection time (milliseconds) = 0
                optimizer estimated row count: 51.50
                optimizer estimated cost: 810.94
            Source result set:
                Index Scan ResultSet for CHILDUPDATE using index TESTINDEX at read committed isolation level using exclusive row locking chosen by the optimizer
                Number of opens = 1
                Rows seen = 2500
                Rows filtered = 0
                Fetch Size = 1
                    constructor time (milliseconds) = 0
                    open time (milliseconds) = 0
                    next time (milliseconds) = 32
                    close time (milliseconds) = 0
                    next time in milliseconds/row = 0

                scan information:
                    Bit set of columns fetched={0, 1, 2}
                    Number of columns fetched=3
                    Number of deleted rows visited=0
                    Number of pages visited=42
                    Number of rows qualified=2500
                    Number of rows visited=2500
                    Scan type=btree
                    Tree height=2
                    start position:
                        None
                    stop position:
                        None
                    qualifiers:
                        Column[0][0] Id: 1
                        Operator: =
                        Ordered nulls: false
                        Unknown return value: false
                        Negate comparison result: false
                    optimizer estimated row count: 51.50
                    optimizer estimated cost: 810.94
total time: ~7 seconds 500 milliseconds
```

Comment: Something very strange is occurring. Can you make this available as a standalone reproduction test? If so, you could file it as a bug with the Derby community and see if any of the developers might be able to help you figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but unfortunately it's not that easy for me to produce a unit test as it relies on other things.  It would be really great if you have some time to try to reproduce this and let me know your findings.  Also please see my other posts on stack overflow about derby for more information on what else I ran into related to this issue and how else it manifests.  Also how would I post this bug with the Derby community?  Thanks :)

Comment: Okay I discovered that if i set "derby.storage.pageSize" to "32768" it fixes this issue, but not fully. If i add more columns to the table, just a few, the performance goes slow again.  This is a serious issue because even if it would work with the number of columns i really want in this table (about 15, nothing large, no huge varchars), this suggests that it will again slow down significantly once i reach some amount of records in the table and issue an update for all of them to change one column for example (please see my other derby posts in this forum).  Please help :)

Comment: my other derby post for more information and related issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765186/apache-derby-database-performance-slow-with-a-foreign-key